# TypeScript function that works on all numerical array types

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, generics, constraints

I am trying to write a function that works on all of the JavaScript array types, e.g. on `number[]`, `Float32Array` etc. It should return the same type that it gets as a parameter. A simple example would be:

```
function addOne<T>(a: T) : T {
  return a.map((x: number) => x + 1);
}
```

The function should be able to use all methods common to all array types (not just `map`).

I also tried

```
type NumberArray<T> = T extends Array<number>
  ? Array<number>
  : Float32Array; // other array types skipped for brevity


function addOne<T>(a: NumberArray<T>): NumberArray<T> {
  return a.map((x: number) => x + 1);
}
```

but I get

```
TS2322: Type 'number[] | Float32Array' is not assignable to type 'NumberArray<T>'.   Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'NumberArray<T>'.
```

What would the TypeScript signature of such a function be? I also want to be able to create several such function and pass them as a parameter to another function (all properly typed, of course). A trivial example would be:

```
function doSomethingWithArray(a, func) {
  return func(a);
}
```

The type of `a` should define which signature of `func` is used.
I have no problems running this in JS, but when trying to add proper TS typing, the TS compiler complains (I am running with `"strict": true` compiler option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript does not have a built-in `NumericArray` type of which `Array<number>` and `Float32Array`-et-cetera are subtypes that gives you access to all common methods.  Nor can I think of a one-or-two line solution that will give that to you.  Instead, if you really need this, I'd suggest you create your own type.  For example:

```
interface NumericArray {
  every(predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: this) => unknown, thisArg?: any): boolean;
  fill(value: number, start?: number, end?: number): this;
  filter(predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: this) => any, thisArg?: any): this;
  find(predicate: (value: number, index: number, obj: this) => boolean, thisArg?: any): number | undefined;
  findIndex(predicate: (value: number, index: number, obj: this) => boolean, thisArg?: any): number;
  forEach(callbackfn: (value: number, index: number, array: this) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
  indexOf(searchElement: number, fromIndex?: number): number;
  join(separator?: string): string;
  lastIndexOf(searchElement: number, fromIndex?: number): number;
  readonly length: number;
  map(callbackfn: (value: number, index: number, array: this) => number, thisArg?: any): this;
  reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: this) => number): number;
  reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: this) => number, initialValue: number): number;
  reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: this) => U, initialValue: U): U;
  reduceRight(callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: this) => number): number;
  reduceRight(callbackfn: (previousValue: number, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: this) => number, initialValue: number): number;
  reduceRight<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: number, currentIndex: number, array: this) => U, initialValue: U): U;
  reverse(): this;
  slice(start?: number, end?: number): this;
  some(predicate: (value: number, index: number, array: this) => unknown, thisArg?: any): boolean;
  sort(compareFn?: (a: number, b: number) => number): this;
  toLocaleString(): string;
  toString(): string;
  [index: number]: number;
}
```

That's kind of long, but I created it by merging the existing array typings in [**`lib.es5.d.ts`**](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c552a4bf827cf56680d5cb1510dd948a3787ea38/lib/lib.es5.d.ts), and changing any reference to the particular array type with [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types), meaning "the current subtype of the `NumericArray` interface".  So, for example, `Array<number>`'s `map()` method returns an `Array<number>`, while a `Float32Array`'s `map()` method returns a `Float32Array`.  The `this` type can be used to represent this relationship between the array type and the return type.

If you care about post-ES5 functionality you can go and merge those methods in also, but this should be enough to demonstrate the basic approach.

You could *try* to write something that computes `NumericArray` programmatically, but I wouldn't want to.  It is likely to be more fragile and more confusing than the manual `NumericArray` definition above, and probably take nearly as many lines.

---

Then, I'd write your `addOne()` in terms of `NumericArray`:

```
function addOne<T extends NumericArray>(a: T): T {
  return a.map((x: number) => x + 1);
}
```

And you can verify that it works as expected for `Array<number>` and `Float32Array`:

```
const arr = addOne([1, 2, 3]);
// const arr: number[]
console.log(arr); // [2, 3, 4];
arr.unshift(1); // okay

const float32Arr = addOne(new Float32Array([1, 2, 3]));
// const float32Arr: this
console.log(float32Arr) // this: {0: 2, 1: 3, 2: 4}
console.log(float32Arr.buffer.byteLength); // 12
```

---

And your `doSomethingWithArray` would look like this:

```
function doSomethingWithArray<T extends NumericArray, R>(a: T, func: (a: T) => R) {
  return func(a);
}
console.log(doSomethingWithArray([4, 5, 6], x => x.unshift(3))); // 4
console.log(doSomethingWithArray(new Int8Array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), x => x.byteLength)); // 5
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=22&pln=23&pc=28#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIFcC21gIIJRRwCeyA3gFDLIQBu0xAFAA5QQAmuckAXMo7TgAbdBD4gsAI2gAaZKHYQAHuKmzkcQiT5gAFsADOASmQBeAHzJ0IANYgA9gHcQcvYYIBzAPx84IYkZ8kvb2QhB+ANxUyDDAQkICwqKqmNJQcgZgmmA+yBKp6hAg7Ln5aYHIbgZR1LFCkFAsbJwI3GL8giLtZeoKyilpcppExDr6xmaWfsSu45650xVVNTEKTRxcvB1J3Wrp8sX9eXty9pIAVmOGJhbIwaHhLpVzUN6+-hU9UMgAPlaHsRAHBWgPYAElDkp1i02nxEl0Br1IYj9mdLs9rpM7iEwn5Zu5XgsPiiQfYoABRRC6RiteKSRA2GAgOGdZLHAr7PoqdmDDRaUYYia3Wj2YDsfEGebvAJ8EVilZcgDyMEYBnCUAQunJYWw4BRchgUHsmAhiiUpT2nz2K3OopAqogzE03DJuUyUFAHgq7s9KyEcEypuUyodmk12ogurA+piRpNkItHKtHJWbDg7HsICEpDCIA8ehJ0UwcGYNOEQnpCEZzO2CJ5SLNMeG2kFN0sXwlUo0xMFqY46CQZbpDKZcNYdGA9nQBgAajsYwh0IQimA53WO8hF8vwEHuRvmwKqm361Bk2k++wBxAhxWRzX1rRJ9O12yN1u2OAX7sOXJ3yvd02-JXEK7YnAcwBgMAwhfiiZ7QBeV4ADwAKrmDelbVmObCPlOs7zsgyG-kuH6rvhb7Ef+yInkMQGtlihHgZB0H4chFTIQhSAAErAB4uhgOhd5YROuEwdRm4UZ+ZFgX+O5UfutFHliXxwVAHEQNxvH8bSt5VqO-Djjhz5ST+4nbqR67SRJYAAWJB7AceG6gBBUFCKJymFtQzRXhpfEoWh2kYXpD5PnhdYMTJ5mvpZZk2fJIz2fRchOUxrksWxfb0FAaqMEs4wrAYQi4NemTZImvJFCUsHAflxrXuOMJbPCUUmVygHxXRtzWHYThPFUXaLEEOKPDVUBacaTpsAAYiAuSMHAMaSLBSmWtV0RgPYAAy9i0hAADKYAenmOV8D6eYrOt+2HR4x3IKdHgrAA2q1J4ALqFgAvhQX0wNYCCQZmGjsOwipAohAAqNBKJAxQGGgWA4Pg-JofNyBgxUEOUJ5EBgEuIAaAAdMWpaMHulpYkoyAANTIAAjEYUSfRQCCZpkfLfKYgPA0CjAPTTcgAExyAAzC99MUAA9OLm4s2AbMog9L1MyzDz40I9jXcM9PIJLyAPYLyBC3IAAsL1RMM+PWAY+gwPxdMRNrUv2DYJBfczICszAavcEL-MEOznMg9eQKOMgk1e2APt+yQPN88g+si0YYs627Hvh5HhDAUr7sq2r12e-Y3u+4QJg61UfBkAADHw+s03whtx3wRufSnOfq4w+eF37+OSOgMAwNA3fEJAG1FPmuhazrNP899v3-XjGa7bVbh5gA6hBuhR8Q4OQ9D7Cwxg2AeojIxyJxyN8GDBq-XCKNo1inEmJjyBsDjUB4z9IAIHNYvN8rYSq23BeS99Cr3XpvHmRs5AAFY5AADYXpyAprcJQFt3bW34kLROE8pZGyzgYVu10gHYGXh4NeehwHB2QBCMAAAOcBvMBbC2NtA0WiDyaD2HqPPQid7Y6ygUAA)

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but why not just solve this with an overloaded signature?

Comment: Overload what?  Can you explain, preferably with a playground link?

Comment: the `this` trick is very very nice. Actually it's the first time it makes me want to use an interface over a type.

Comment: @jcalz [Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAMwrgdgxgLglgewgAgIYBN0HkIFMAUqAXMhGALYBGuATgNoC6AlCWVbYwNyiSyIoZseQiQBiAGwSoYAZgBMAQRo1UATxbIJU2YuVru4aPCRpMOAsVIVq9BsgA+mydPlKV61tY53HWl7vdkAG9gZGQaXBgwGgEAOnJUAAd8fAAPT3YaJmQAXgA+ZFTkAGpkAEYmbgBfYGAoJABnGDRlXNMhAjoygBpkOV6ZZm4AemHkeogmlpoMm0Y6xoRxXFjJAHNCZUrkUeQ6fuQZXoAWBm5UZVjIBoALOBAYfArOHbGEAGs1WompkGcdNxtQTmfB4ADuTm0rj0qnwXV6B0GTEqwF2P2afyhARIMDuDQWkyWK3W+Ex-jc2V2uLgDRIQQADCQDmUSEc+iRjjUfkTVggNmSAZdKGAQCBaLFKKoYLgADK4CBrXHbXZlORAA). I realize now that the last requirement with passing functions wouldn't work that way, though.

Comment: You'd also have to overload every function a bunch of times, since OP apparently wants "`number[]`, `Float32Array`, **etc**" where "etc" implies the whole menagerie of [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray) subtypes.

Comment: How would I create a new instance of the numeric array type within the `addOne` function?

Comment: @porst17 I don't know, maybe `filter(()=>false)`? That's out of the scope of the original question, so I'm not sure that a comment section is the best place to discuss this.  But my guess would be that functions that deal with `NumericArray` will need to ask the caller to pass in whatever you need, such as a constructor that produces a new array of the right type... maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKkZgW).

Answer (score 1):

I was reminded of this question today and came up with something I find interesting:

```js
function addOne <T extends NumericArray[number]> (a: T)
    : Narrow<T, NumericArray> {
        return a.map(x => x + 1) }

type NumericArray = [
    Array<number>,
    Int8Array,
    Uint8Array,
    Uint8ClampedArray,
    Int16Array,
    Uint16Array,
    Int32Array,
    Uint32Array,
    Float32Array,
    Float64Array
];

type Narrow<
    T, L extends unknown[] = [],
    R1 extends unknown[] = {
        [K in keyof L]: T extends L[K] ? { type: T } : never
    },
    R2 = unknown extends T ? never : R1[number],
> = [R2] extends [{ type: unknown }] ? R2['type'] : never
```

I like how it has a different maintainability profile than jcalz's answer, which I still believe made more sense for your use case because the API is cleaner and you had to write a lot of functions for the same set of variants. That was a lot of grunt work though and I would see myself reaching for this second solution if I had to do this for different sets of variants.

I guess the API could be a little cleaner if `Narrow` took a union instead of a tuple but I don't know how computationally intensive that would be to add this step.

Answer (score 0):

Your last question has a simple solution

```js
function apply<T, U>(a: T, func: (x: T) => U): U {
    return func(a);
}
```

---

UPDATE

This seems to work and I fail to see what is unsafe about it.

```js
type NumberArray = 
    { map:(f:(x:number) => number) => any } 
    & ArrayLike<number> 
    & Iterable<number>;


function addOne<T extends NumberArray>(a: T):T {
    return a.map((x: number) => x + 1)
}
```

I don't think it's possible to do what you want with `number[]` and `Float32Array` because there is no such thing as a Float32 type in Javascript and we can't express something like "I want a generic `Wrapper` around a type `Number | Float32 | ...`" in Typescript anyway. Without these 2 features I don't see how it could be done.

We could do something like that which makes Typescript happy:

```js
type NumberArray =
    {
        map: Function
        // define other methods there
    }
    & ArrayLike<number> 
    & Iterable<number>;


function addOne<T extends NumberArray>(a: T): T {
    return a.map((x: number) => x + 1)
}
```

But it allows you to `map` to a type other than number:

```js
function addOne<T extends NumberArray>(a: T): T {
    return a.map((x: number):string => x + '!') // woops
}
```

We could do the following:

```js
type NumberArray =
    {
        map:(f:(x:number) => number) => NumberArray
        // define other methods there
    }
    & ArrayLike<number> 
    & Iterable<number>;


function addOne<T extends NumberArray>(a: T): T {
    return a.map((x: number) => x + 1)
}
```

but then we would get an error.

```
Type 'NumberArray' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'NumberArray' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ map: (f: (x: number) => number) => NumberArray; } & ArrayLike<number> & Iterable<number>
```

it can only be used like so, which looses type information (maybe it's OK for you though)

```js
function addOne(a: NumberArray) {
    return a.map((x: number):number => x + 1)
}
```

---

On a side note, I don't see the value of creating an `addOne` function which can only work with array-like objects. That's very specific. The whole point of `map` is to decouple the data structure from the transformation.

The following is more flexible because `addOne` doesn't need to know about where it's going to be used and the type information is preserved:

```js
const addOne = (x: number) => x + 1;

addOne(3);
[1, 2, 3].map(addOne);
Float32Array.from([1,2,3]).map(addOne);
```

It doesn't solve your problem though: as soon as we define a function which needs to accept a `NumberArray` as argument we are back where we started...

Comment: `addOne` was just a trivial example to illustrate function signature. That function should be able to use all array methods as stated in the OP, not just map. In fact, I am dealing with non-trivial numerical algorithms, but that wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: My answer is just a less exhaustive and less elegant version of jcalz's but it's the exact same idea. As for your intention, your question was very clear but I was mislead by your example.